# Are the posthoc results of the Linear Mixed Effect model valid?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, post-hoc, lsmeans

I'm running a linear mixed model on a data frame that consists of 3 variables: `ID` (n=11), `region` (n=3) and `distance`. The `lme` and posthoc analysis works for comparing whether there is a difference in distances between regions.

This works fine:

```
lmod <- lme(distance~region, data = dat, random=~1|ID)
```

However, when i want to compare whether there is a difference in distances between ID's for a single region, I get the message:

> Warning message: In qt((1 - level)/adiv, df) : NaNs produced.

Example:

```
lmod <-lme(distance~ID, data = dat, random=~1|region)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: anova 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
   238.3404 250.7031 -113.1702

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | region
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    0.525893 1.552832

Fixed effects: distance ~ ID 
                Value Std.Error DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 1.3707517 0.7195083 58 1.905123  0.0617
IDRTBC97    1.5807197 0.5966171 58 2.649471  0.0104
IDRTBC98    1.4744081 0.5966171 58 2.471280  0.0164
IDRTBC99    0.7074731 0.6944476 58 1.018757  0.3125
 Correlation: 
         (Intr) IDRTBC97 IDRTBC98
IDRTBC97 -0.562                  
IDRTBC98 -0.562  0.677           
IDRTBC99 -0.483  0.582    0.582  

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-1.7259489 -0.7290054 -0.1385774  0.7271977  2.5181760 

Number of Observations: 62
Number of Groups: 1
```

### post hoc

```
emmeans(lmod, list(pairwise ~ ID), adjust = "tukey")

  $`emmeans of ID`

   ID     emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
   RTBC96   1.37 0.720  0      NaN      NaN
   RTBC97   2.95 0.626  0      NaN      NaN
   RTBC98   2.85 0.626  0      NaN      NaN
   RTBC99   2.08 0.720  0      NaN      NaN

d.f. method: containment 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$`pairwise differences of ID`
 contrast        estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 RTBC96 - RTBC97   -1.581 0.597 58 -2.649  0.0495 
 RTBC96 - RTBC98   -1.474 0.597 58 -2.471  0.0753 
 RTBC96 - RTBC99   -0.707 0.694 58 -1.019  0.7392 
 RTBC97 - RTBC98    0.106 0.479 58  0.222  0.9961 
 RTBC97 - RTBC99    0.873 0.597 58  1.464  0.4658 
 RTBC98 - RTBC99    0.767 0.597 58  1.285  0.5758 

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 

Warning message:
In qt((1 - level)/adiv, df) : NaNs produced
```

As far as I understand, I'm getting the warning message since I only have one group and the degrees of freedom are zero. However, I'm still getting the comparison between the ID's.

My question is: Can I use the p values of the pairwise differences of ID generated here, or are these invalid?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you running the example code you show above on a subset of the data from a single region?  If so, it doesn't seem to make sense to use `lme` and include the grouping variable: I would just do `lm(distance~ID, data = dat, subset=(region=="region1"))` and go from there ...

Comment: Yes that's right Ben, sorry i failed to mention this! I'll try your recommendation, thanks for the reply!

Comment: I'm guessing that Ben nailed it. The intuition is that you can't estimate the SE of a mean when you have only one region, but when you compare them, the region effect cancels out, so it doesn't matter that you can't estimate it.

Comment: @BenBolker: Conceptually, does it make sense to treat ID as (1) a random grouping factor in the model lme(distance~region, data = dat, random=~1|ID) and (2) a fixed factor in the lm model relating distance to ID for a specific region? These two treatments seem to come at things from different angles - is it valid to assume that both angles hold in the same study? For example, is it valid to assume that the IDs in the lme model are representative of a larger universe of IDs while at the same time the IDs in the lm model are the sole IDs of interest in the study?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement: I agree it doesn't make much sense to me, but I wasn't going to go there ...

Comment: @BenBolker:  I've seen other people on this forum assume both of those things simultaneosly and it seems to me that it's a case of "you can't have your cake and eat it too".  